# how to catch "index out of range" exception in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

how can I catch "index out of range" exception in Qt? I used the try/catch but looks like it's not working.

```
try {
    QStringList list;
    QString str = list[1];
} catch (...) {
    qDebug()<<"error";
}
```

From Windows XP, I can see below dialog pop up:

```
---------------------------
K.exe - Application Error
---------------------------
The instruction at "0x0040144c" referenced memory at "0x00040012". The memory could not be "written".


Click on OK to terminate the program
Click on CANCEL to debug the program
---------------------------
OK   Cancel   
---------------------------
```

here is why I need to do this. Some of our not-so-experienced engineers need to use a smarll portion of Qt C++ language to do some automation test work. We can't force them to be using QList as an expreienced designer. So I'll try to catch and log the error so that their automation test script won't crash and easy to find out the bug spot. – zhongzhu yesterday

Comment: From looking at the docs, it doesn't look like that is supposed to throw an exception.

Comment: Qt never throws any exceptions.

Comment: @n.m., That should be a handy piece of advice should I ever use it.

Comment: If you give some explanation of the reason you want to this, we could probably come up with an alternative solution.

Comment: here is why I need to do this. Some of our not-so-experienced engineers need to use a smarll portion of Qt C++ language to do some automation test work. We can't force them to be using QList as an expreienced designer. So I'll try to catch and log the error so that their automation test script won't crash and easy to find out the bug spot.

Comment: You can subclass `QList` and reimplement `operator []` so it throws exceptions, and force your engineers to use this class instead.

Answer (score 1):

As commenters have pointed out, you can't.

Although Qt supports exceptions, it doesn't use them. Somebody over at qt-project's forum suggested it was to increase portability (since some platforms don't support exception handling).

The alternative would be to either check the values yourself before trying to access them, or to build your own wrappers for the classes that need exception handeling.

An example that illustrates the difference:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QStringList>
#include <vector>
void t1()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(2);
    vec.push_back(4);

    qDebug() << "Val: " << vec.at(3);
}


void t2()
{
    QStringList sl;
    sl << "Foo" << "Bar" << "Herp" << "Derp";

    qDebug() << sl.at(0);
    qDebug() << sl.at(5);
}

void t3()
{
    qDebug() << "Going down!";
    abort();
}

int main()
{
    try {
        t1();
        //t2();
        //t3();
    } catch (...) {
        qDebug() << "Close one...";
    }
}
```

Comment: so what I saw (the exception dialog on Windows XP) is from C++, not Qt?

Comment: Well, if you get the same dialog I do, it's actually not from an exception but rather a QT_ASSERT which results in an `abort();` call.

Comment: Added an example. As you can see only vector throws an exception. Without the try/catch you'll get a similar kind of termination of the application though.

Comment: I tried your example. t1() throws an exception. t2() throws the same "error message" as I posted （"The instruction at "0x0040144c" referenced memory at "0x00040012". The memory could not be "written"）. Do you think it's an "abort()"? But abort()'s error message is quite different from it. abort()'s message is: "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information."

Comment: On Windows, Q_ASSERT doesn't call abort(), it calls _CrtDbgReport().

Comment: The error message is from the CRT's runtime checks informing you of an invalid memory access. Like Zhongzhu says, the one issued by the CRT when `abort()` is called is a little bit different. It's not an exception, and it's not an ASSERT either.

Answer (score -1):

Check number of records yourself

```
QList<int> list;
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
    qDebug() << list.at(i);
```

or use the QListIterator

```
QList<int> list;
QListIterator<int> iterator;
while(iterator.hasNext())
    qDebug() << iterator.next();
```

Comment: That wasn't the point. If you don't access the list with invalid index, obviously there won't be any problems. The problem is how to catch the usage of invalid index.

Comment: You must not use an invalid index or subclass QList and throw your exception yourself in the at() operator: ``if(index < 0 || index > list.size()) throw exception; else return QList::at(index)``. Something like that

Comment: Yes, I know that invalid indeces are bad, but sometimes bugs happen. And at least using Windows and mingw, invalid index bugs are a big pain to trace. It seems that in Linux the debugger shows an usable stack trace. Subclassing the QList might be an answer.